# How can I eliminate quotes and [] from mysql query result (nodejs)

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am doing a select query on MySQL database using NodeJS.
How can I get the expected result? The data type in mysql is varchar.
I want to eliminate [] and ' '.

What I want:

```
test1
```

My code:

```
app.get('/info', function(request, response){
   var query = 'SELECT title FROM community where id = abcd';
   db.query(query, function(err, filelist, fields){
   if(err) console.log(err);
      console.log(filelist);
      const titleArr = filelist.map(item=>item.title);
      console.log(titleArr);

});
```

The result I got:

```
[ TextRow { title: 'test1' }]
[ 'test1' ]
```

Comment: just get the first element of the array `titleArr[0]`?. You can't console.log without quotes thou since it's a string

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Why didn't I think of it? lol